# Matplotlib: indicate the max value on the grah

Tags: python, matplotlib

My initial dataframe looks like this:

```
       exp     gamma
0   -0.068958     0.100
1   -0.052961     0.200
2   -0.035676     0.300
3   -0.029389     0.400
4   -0.025585     0.500
5   -0.022839     0.600
6   -0.020527     0.700
7   -0.018606     0.800
8   -0.016844     0.900
...
917  0.000601   611.731
918  0.000600   627.431
919  0.000589   636.132
920  0.000568   637.132
921  0.000551   641.432
922  0.000559   669.333
923  0.000544   677.534
924  0.000532   690.135
925  0.000520   702.935
926  0.000497   704.735
```

What I would like to dO:

```
1) indicate the max value of exp on the graph
```

What I tried so far: 
`max=df['exp'].max()
df.plot(x='gamma',y='exp')`

and sorry to say, but I have no clue for printing the max on the graph! Thanks

Comment: If you google for the title you chose for your question the first result will be the duplicate question.

Comment: Yes thanks but I did not understand it

Comment: Where exactly lies your problem of understanding? Did you try any of the solutions from that Q&A? At which point did it fail?